# Obtener usuario con SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE

Tags: select

Estoy tratando de llamar la información de mi base de datos. La base se llama **USUARIOS** y estoy llamando la columna **NOMBRE**. Cuando doy click a un nombre de una sola palabra si me trae la información. Esta es la tabla:

[image: datos]

Los nombres son enlaces. Cuando doy click sobre *Eduardo* me despliega la siguiente información:

```
id = 1  
nombre = Eduardo  
actividad = trabajador 1. Trabajo en oficina, ...
```

Pero cuando doy click sobre *Jose Manuel* o *Juan*... (nombres con + de 1 palabra) no trae la información y me manda el mensaje:

> La página no existe.

Este es mi código:

```
public static function obtener_usuario($conexion, $nombre) { 
    $usuario = null;  
    if (isset($conexion)) { 
        try {  
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre"; 
            $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);  
            $sentencia->bindParam(':nombre', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $sentencia->execute();  
            $resultado = $sentencia > fetch();  
            if (!empty($resultado)) {  
                $usuario = new Usuario($resultado['id'], $resultado['nombre'], $resultado['actividad']);  
            }  
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {  
            print 'ERROR' . $ex->getMessage();  
        }  
    }  
    return $usuario;  

    // /* se recomienda el cierre explícito */  
    $sentencia->free_result();  
    $sentencia >close(); 
     $sql->close();  
}
```

He estado leyendo y es cuestión de agregar unas comillas sencillas o paréntesis en alguna parte pero he intentado varios arreglos y no me ha funcionado.

Podría dividir los nombres en varias columnas (1ernombre, 2do nombre, 1er apellido...) pero debe haber alguna forma de solucionarlo sin crear mas columnas. Solicito la ayuda de un experto.

Comment: Intenta formular mejor tus preguntas, te recomiendo revisar el recorrido para evitar este tipo de situaciones [es.stackoverflow.com/tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). ¿Has intentado separar el nombre de dos palabras y hacer un where doble? Tipo: `select * from .... where nombre = "xxx" or nombre = "xxx"`.

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta. He editado mi pregunta para ser un poco mas claro. Tengo pensado agregar mas columnas pero para otra información mas relevante (EDAD, ESTADO_CIVIL, CARACTERISTICAS, ...) pero el nombre no lo quiero dividir en columnas y ser capaz de ver la información dando clic sobre el nombre completo.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Como dice @FerdysDuran en su respuesta, debes filtrar por `ID`, no por nombre. En la BD puede haber más de una persona que se llame `José` o `Juan Manuel` o `María` por tanto el nombre nunca es una columna identificatoria segura. Sugiero que hagas uso de minúsculas en la formulación de tus preguntas, es de mal gusto escribir todo en mayúsculas. Saludos.

Comment: He condicionado la variable nombre para que no existan nombres repetidos. Mi intención de llamar la variable nombre es porque quiero usar las llamadas "url amistosas". Efectivamente con la columna id he logrado llamar los datos que se requieren pero en mi url me aparece index/usuario/2 y yo quiero que aparezca index/usuario/jose-manuel. Lo uso en <a href="<?php echo RUTA_USUARIO . '/' . $nombre->obtener_nombre() ?>">

Comment: es la parte donde la ruta index/usuario/eduardo me despliega la información correcta pero la ruta index/usuario/jose-manuel me manda el mensaje "pagina no encontrada" (el guion entre jose y manuel es porque uso str-replace...

Comment: @Ferdys Duran Lo solucione de la siguiente manera: Al momento de ser enviada la información a la base de datos, agregue str_replace() para que en la base de datos los nombres aparezcan sin espacios (remplace el espacio por guion en la base de datos). Para mostrar la informacion en la pagina vuelvo a usar str_replace() a la inversa para remplazar guiones por espacios. Tengo la duda: ¿Afectara esto el funcionamiento de la pagina?, ¿Afecta al momento de las busquedas?, ¿Afecta a los robots buscadores de google, yahoo, etc.?. De esta forma mis url se ven index/usuarios/jose-manuel tal como quiero

Comment: Hola Eduardo, tu solucion esta bien, me quedo la duda, en la base de datos seguís guardando los datos normalmente, es decir con espacio? porque esa forma es correcta, lo que debes hacer es eliminar el guion del medio a la hora de consultar la base para que haga la igualdad correcta, (no agregar el guion del medio en la base de datos y eliminarlo para mostrarlo)

Comment: @Sebastian No, ahora los datos de la culumna $nombre los guardo sustituyendo el espacio por guion. Tengo pensado crear una variable que llamare $url que tome el valor del nombre pero sustituya los espacios por puntos o guiones (¿que es mas recomendable, puntos o guiones?, he visto que paginas como facebook usan puntos) y sera la que me sirva para las url amigables. Así mantendré en contenido de la columna $nombre con caracteres y espacios tal como se ingresan en el formulario.

Comment: Lo importante es que mantengas la nomenclatura, es decir, siempre usa el mismo caracter, o punto o guion. Pero te recomiendo que guardes los datos en la base de datos como tienen que ir, sin el guion del medio. Para consultar los datos le agregas el guion del medio dentro de la variable que pasas como parametro :nombre.

Comment: @Sebastian Esa es mi pregunta principal, ¿Como le agrego el guion de en medio a la variable :nombre cuando la paso como parámetro?. Ahí es cuando tengo el problema pues las variables :nombre con una sola palabra si recupera la información pero las variables :nombre con 2 o mas palabras no se enlazan con la base de datos

Comment: Cual es el metodo que estas usando al hacer click en el nombre?

Answer (score 1):

Deberias tomar el campo de la columna 0 (ID) de esa row (linea) que estas haciendo click,

y asi traera especificamente la información de ese usuario.

seria algo así el select

```
select * from  usuarios where id= 'el id enviado'
```

Answer (score 0):

Como todos te dicen, deberias tomar el ID para mandar a llamar los demas campos, pero si aun asi quieres e insistes en que traiga el nombre, prueba con esto

```
SELECT  * FROM usuarios where NOMBRE like '%jose manuel%';
```

con el % nombre % hacemos que busque en la base similitudes asi que puede que si hay mas de un jose manuel te muestre mas de un registro (jose manuel lopez, jose manuel perez etc) lo recomendable seria con el id pero de todos modos te dejo esto para que lo cheques